# Tiling solution for the iPhone that can handle infinite # of tiles

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, tiles

I have been looking at ways to implement a tiling solution on the iPhone/iPad similar to something like Google Maps.  I have looked at examples of how to implement a CATiledLayer into a view that is inside a UIScrollView.  Then when you scroll the view, the tiles request the new data to be shown.  However, this seems to work when you have a finite view size (ie: 3000x3000).  However, how could I work this into a tiling solution for much larger sizes.  Basically, I want to be able to show data as needed for tiles as large as I can.  Can I somehow use CATiledLayer to do this?  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't specifically know how to achieve this with CATiledLayer, but if you look at the example code called ScrollViewSuite, more specifically the "Tiling" project within it, you'll find a way of doing something like Google Maps without using CATiledLayer.

Personally I don't like using CATiledLayer - it seems to have a mind of it's own and can't be monitored easily, for example you don't know when it gets around to finishing it's redrawing etc.